# GNU GRUB error in Windows and Ubuntu dual-boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I tried to install Ubuntu on my desktop. So, I made a virtual [USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) on one of my drives in Windows (I first formatted that drive).

I cannot see either Windows or Ubuntu when I restart the desktop and I jut get this window. I even restored Windows to a previous point, but I still cannot boot Windows. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Here is some general help with installation of ubuntu in recovery  grub. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1599293 if you still have the live cd

Answer (score 0):

Recover your grub. Follow the link 
for a step by step approach

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: I tried this solution, but Ubuntu does not come up! all monitors get black and nothing happen.

Comment: @sam That's why you're supposed to boot from the DVD. Do you know if your system uses UEFI?

Comment: I could use the repair ios file now. I think the reason that both my Windows and Ubuntu do not work is because of defining one of my drives as USB boot! The problem now is formatting that USB drive!